# Можно ли как-то декодировать все группы в re.Match объекте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, decode, re

Есть байты:

```py
b = b'X:\xce\xa4\x91start\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0ende\x85\n\xe0'
```

Надо отдельной функцией с помощью регулярки вытащить оттуда декодируемые части и затем работать с декодированными частями (т.е. со строками). Вытащить части - не проблема. Проблема в том, чтобы в возвращённом [`re.Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) декодировать все группы.
Пример:

```py
import re

b = b'X:\xce\xa4\x91start\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0ende\x85\n\xe0'
m = re.search(b"start(?P<decodable>.+)end", b)

print(m['decodable'])  # b'\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
print(m[0])  # b'start\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0end'
print(m[1])  # b'\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
m = decode_match(m, encoding='utf-8')  # Как реализовать подобное отображение?

# Ожидаемый результат:
print(m['decodable'])  # строка
print(m[0])  # startстрокаend
print(m[1])  # строка
```

Внутри `decode_match` вызовов `bytes.decode` может быть сколько угодно.

Пробовал проитерироваться по `m` и декодировать, но `TypeError: 're.Match' object is not iterable`

Пытался ради эксперимента декодировать нулевую группу:

```py
m[0] = m[0].decode()
```

Но `TypeError: 're.Match' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ThinMagentaLeadership

Comment: @dIm0n Цель именно избежать вызова `.decode()` у каждой группы.

Comment: Не очень понял. Декодировать без вызова `decode`? Или декодировать, вызвав `decode` только один раз?

Comment: @dIm0n Декодировать все группы одним вызовом функции.

Comment: У вас ошибка в присвоении, а не в том, что decode неработает

Comment: @МихаилМуругов так нельзя, скорее всего. Если нужен только 1 вызов `decode`, то сначала найдите `startбайтыend`, декодируйте их один раз, и уже в этой декодированной строке ищите подгруппы без `decode`

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, что `re.Match` может быть новый и что вызовов `decode` может быть сколько угодно

Comment: @dIm0n Думаю, строка `m = decode_match(m, encoding='utf-8')` и так говорит, что `re.Match` может быть новый. Про множественный вызов `bytes.decode` указал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Другой вариант:

```py
import re

def decode_match(match: re.March, encoding='utf-8') -> re.Match:
    decoded_pat = match.re.pattern.decode(encoding)
    return re.match(decoded_pat, match[0].decode(encoding))
```

Возвращает `re.Match` объект с декодированными группами, но:

1. Заново прогоняет регулярку на то, что уже найдено;
2. Не уверен, что
   декодирование исходного паттерна вернёт результат, соответствующий паттерну для поиска в декодированной строке.

Answer (score 2):

Так то все группы можно декодировать в одну строку:

```
d = list(map(bytes.decode, m.groups()))
```

Но присвоить обратно в `re.Match` ничего всё-равно нельзя.

Comment: Я попробовал так, но возвращает только 1 группу https://repl.it/repls/ThreadbareWarlikeScripts

Comment: @dIm0n А она и есть одна. m[0] - это не из groups значение

Comment: @dIm0n Кроме того, кажется тут "жадный" шаблон, его надо как-то ограничивать, чтобы было больше одной группы реально

Comment: Именованные группы отбросятся, такое не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Пока получилось накидать такую функцию:

```py
from itertools import count
import re

def decode_match(match: re.Match, encoding = 'utf-8') -> dict:
    numeric = dict()
    for i in count():
        try:
            numeric[i] = match[i].decode(encoding)
        except IndexError:
            break
    named = {name: group.decode(encoding) for name, group in match.groupdict().items()}
    return {**numeric, **named}
```

Но она возвращает `dict` вместо `re.Match`. Для моей задачи это подходит, но всё же интересно, как получить `re.Match` с декодированными группами.

Comment: Ну если только обёртку над re.Match напишете и ей будете пользоваться. Проблема в том, что обратно в re.Match нельзя ничего присвоить